# UITableView stop updating UI without crashing after adding data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem that is driving me crazy.

I have an UITableView that is ***always*** in editing mode (it has to be).

The user can add new rows to it.

The navigationItem.leftbarButton of the tableViewController pushes a new controller just to do it, let's call it "newRowsVC".

Before the push the tableViewController set itself as the delegate of the newRowsVC, the protocol has only a method:

```
-(void) aNewRowHasBeenCreated
{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I start adding rows and everything works fine, each now row is immediately displayed in the tableViewController ***until*** the last new row will force the tableView to scroll because there won't be anymore screen real estate for it. Here, I have no idea why, the tableView, only it, is as frozen, with no scrollbar and doesn't respond to input. The app continues to run without a crash and I can even dismiss the tableViewController by tapping the navigationItem.rightbarButtonItem.

I can keep creating new rows, they are added to the array, the number of row in the tableView data source is computed correctly. But the table is like dead.

If I dismiss the tableViewController and then I come back to it, I see that all the rows previously created, also the ones not shown as soon as they were created are there!

I really do not have idea of how I can fix this.

The first thing I tried was to force the scroll after the reload of the table but it didn't fix it.

```
-(void) aNewRowHasBeenCreated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES]; 
}
```

I also tried forcing the tableView to scroll to the last row but it didn't fix it.

```
-(void) aNewRowHasBeenCreated
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   [self.tableView setScrollEnabled: YES];
   [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPosition: [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]last object] atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

I check the number of rows each time the table is reloaded. No error, the number is perfect and the new rows data are correctly in the array, also the data for the cells not shown.

I thought it could be because the tableView is always in editing mode so I tried setting it to NO but nothing changes, id din't fix the problem.

Two notes:

1)the tableView has to be the delegate of each one of it's custom cells. They have an UITextField and an UIStepper, handled by the tableViewController. I already tried to not set the tableViewController as the delegate of its custom cells but nothing changes so the problem is not this.

2) self.tableView.bounces = NO but this has nothing to do with the scrolling issue, the scroll is enabled.

Update: After more tests I found that if I remove the dequeue of the reusable custom cell everything works fine, so the problem should be about the reuse.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"MyCell"
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
```

Nicola

Comment: just set [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES]; for UITableview after reload it wil work

Comment: This is the first I tried but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: It would be good to see more of the UITableView code (things like `cellForRow...`) The problem may be in one of those methods.

Comment: When the tableview is frozen, can you pause the app? In this case, you can look at the stack trace of each thread, and you can looking for where your main thread is frozen). Where stop your main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours I got it. As pointed out by Amit the problem was hidden in cellForRowAtIndexPath... It was hard to catch because it didn't happened all the times and the first times I enabled/disabled the cell reusing everything seemed the same so I did not link the problem to it. I got back on it after I tried about all the other options I had been able to think about.

The problem was in the reuse of the cells and the fact that the custom cell has the tableView as its delegate to handle its textView and the stepper without exposing them.

I got rid of all the delagion stuff and exposed the textView and the stepper as public properties of the view. By doing this I was able to set the tableViewController directly to be the delegate of the cell.textView and to add directly a target/action for the stepper.

Everything works flawslessly now.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Nicola